# How do I add an autocompletebox to a datagrid?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I have a datagrid in my application with two columns and 4 rows. Each of the cells needs to be a WPF Toolkit autocompletebox control. I'd like to implement the whole thing using the MVVM pattern. It's easy to populate the cells with text boxes with:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel, Path=Fields}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro">
            <DataGrid.Columns>                    
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Predicate" Binding="{Binding Key}"/>                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But trying to do the same with autocomplete boxes doesn't work for some reason. It compiles and runs but the autocomplete box doesn't open when typing. I used:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel, Path=Fields}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pre">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <wpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel, Path=AvailableFields}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

The definitions for the bound properties are:

```
public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Fields
public IEnumerable<string> AvailableFields
```

Any ideas?

**Update**: The following is the entire XAML based on @Damascus reply. Doesn't work either for some reason.

```
<UserControl x:Class="IKB.Views.IKBInputView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:IKB.ViewModels"
             xmlns:wpfToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Input.Toolkit"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <vm:IKBInputVM x:Key="viewModel" />
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">        
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding viewModel, Path=Fields}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="True" CanUserSortColumns="True" AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Pre">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <wpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.viewModel.AvailableFields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: For this XAML to work, `AvailableFields` has to be child of `Fields`, same as `Key` and `Value` are children of `Fields` in case of TextBox example.

Comment: So how do I make it so that the ItemsSource for the autocomplete is not a child of Fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are not in the same `DataContext` here.

Each `AutoCompleteBox` will have its own `DataContext` (not sure about its exact position, but it is related to the current cell itself) , so it will look for the ItemsSource in a wrong place.

Your `Binding` has to refer to the original DataContext.
Assuming that this DataGrid is in a UserControl, try:

```
<wpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.viewModel.AvailableFields,
           RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}} />
```

This should do the trick (it will now look into the `UserControl`'s DataContext, which is the one you are working with)

Comment: Didn't work for some reason. The XAML won't fit in a comment so I'm attaching it as an edit to the question.

Comment: Got it to work. It should be `<wpfToolkit:AutoCompleteBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.AvailableFields, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />`. Thanks!